# Positioning an input field above the enclosing div with z-index

Tags: css, input, z-index, css-position

I have a form with a series of divs enclosing single rows of data and inputs inside those divs.
I would like to render the inputs in css as "close" symbols but I'm not able to position them "above" the top left corner, using negative margins or negative position. Z-index doesn't seem to do the trick… they end un hidden in the surrounding white area.

```
<div class="item-in-cart">
<input type="submit" name="delete[1]" class="delete" value="elimina">
</div>
<div class="item-in-cart">
<input type="submit" name="delete[2]" class="delete" value="elimina">
</div>
[...]

.item-in-cart {
width: 330px;
overflow: hidden;
border: 1px dashed #222;
margin-bottom: 20px;
padding: 15px;
position: relative;
}
.item-in-cart .delete {
display: block;
width: 25px;
height: 25px;
background: url(/assets/images/delete.png) no-repeat 0 0;
text-indent: -9999px;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
position: absolute;
top: -12px;
left: -12px;
z-index: 200;}
```

Why is that so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first off you're going to want to close your div elements. then you want to do what @adrift said about adding position to the inputs. then you'll notice that while your positioning, z-index is working, they aren't going above the top left because you have `overflow:hidden` set. take that out, and there ya go. here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/CpmdV/1/

Comment: Yep! Overflow was causing the issue. Thanks.